# Clear down following form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a multistage form in which options are dependent upon previous choices. In the event of a user going back and changing the contents of a form field, I need to reset all the **following fields**. The fields are not all direct siblings of each other and are either inputs or select boxes. I'm using JQuery to manage the form.

What is the best way to clear down all the following fields in the form?

For example, in the following if name[RollerBlindMeasurementType] changes, need to clear down name[RollerBlindWidth], name=[RollerBlindHeight] and name[RollerBlindFixingType]

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
          <label for="RollerBlindMeasurementType">Measurement Type</label>
          <select name="RollerBlindMeasurementType">
            <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="Blind size">Blind Size</option>
            <option value="Recess">Recess</option>
            <option value="Cloth size">Cloth Size</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns RollerBlindWidth unseen cr">
          <label for="RollerBlindWidth">Width (mm)</label>
          <input type="text" name="RollerBlindWidth">
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns RollerBlindHeight unseen cr">
          <label for="RollerBlindHeight">Height (mm)</label>
          <input type="text" name="RollerBlindHeight">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-4 columns RollerBlindFixingType unseen cr">
                <label>Fixing Type</label>
                <select name="RollerBlindFixingType">
                <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
                <option value="Face Fix">Face fix</option>
                <option value="Top Fix">Top fix</option>
                <option value="Side Fix">Side fix</option>
              </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: use in-common classes to associate the controls to each other. Then you can just clear everything with the associated class.

Comment: I can't see how I could make that work. If I had 10 fields, would I not need a separate class for each of the next 9, another class for each of the next 8, another for the next 7 and so on?

Comment: nope. Because then you can use script to find all the _subsequent_ fields which have the class. jQuery can do this for you.

Comment: So how would I find subsequent occurrences of the class given that they are not siblings?